# Complex MySQL SELECT, GROUP, SUM.

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID,
       A.CLIENT_ID,
       A.PROJECT_ID,
       A.USER_ID,
       A.UTL_DTSTAMP,
       /* DATE_FORMAT(A.UTL_DTSTAMP,'%H:%i:%s') AS UTL_DTSTAMP, */
       A.UTL_LATITUDE,
       A.UTL_LONGITUDE,
       A.UTL_EVENT,
       A.UTL_ACTION,
       /* DURATION in seconds  */
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, A.UTL_DTSTAMP, B.UTL_DTSTAMP) AS UTL_DURATION
FROM   tbl_user_time_log A
       INNER JOIN tbl_user_time_log B
               ON B.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID = ( A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID + 1 )
WHERE  A.USER_ID = '465605'
       /* Between current pay period Start date and Current pay period end date */
       /* First day of the week is Monday.*/
       AND ( A.UTL_DTSTAMP BETWEEN '2018-01-22' AND '2018-01-28' )
       /* Filter out Clock Out. */
       AND A.UTL_EVENT <> 'CLOCK OUT'
ORDER  BY A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID ASC;
```

...which returns the following results:

[image]

Question:

How can I **GROUP BY** UTL_ACTION and **SUM** its grouped values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM (
    SELECT A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID,
       A.CLIENT_ID,
       A.PROJECT_ID,
       A.USER_ID,
       A.UTL_DTSTAMP,
       /* DATE_FORMAT(A.UTL_DTSTAMP,'%H:%i:%s') AS UTL_DTSTAMP, */
       A.UTL_LATITUDE,
       A.UTL_LONGITUDE,
       A.UTL_EVENT,
       A.UTL_ACTION,
       /* DURATION in seconds  */
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, A.UTL_DTSTAMP, B.UTL_DTSTAMP) AS UTL_DURATION
    FROM   tbl_user_time_log A
       INNER JOIN tbl_user_time_log B
           ON B.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID = ( A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID + 1 )
    WHERE  A.USER_ID = '465605'
       /* Between current pay period Start date and Current pay period end date */
       /* First day of the week is Monday.*/
       AND ( A.UTL_DTSTAMP BETWEEN '2018-01-22' AND '2018-01-28' )
       /* Filter out Clock Out. */
       AND A.UTL_EVENT <> 'CLOCK OUT'
    ORDER  BY A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID ASC)
GROUP BY UTL_ACTION
```

?

Comment: error: Every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: Try again. Of course, if the script does what you want, you can remove all the uneccessay columns i the SELECT statement.

Comment: Then forget it, it was a longshot :)

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to comment you own answer, but after giving an alias and that works, add the GROUP BY UTL_ACTION part.

Comment: Alright. I'm going to accept your answer because it inspired me to go in the right direction. I've added a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution inspired by [Nicky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/517841/nicky).

```
SELECT PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID,
       USER_ID,
       UTL_ACTION,
       SUM(UTL_DURATION) AS DURATION_TOTAL       
  FROM (

SELECT A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID,
       A.CLIENT_ID,
       A.PROJECT_ID,
       A.USER_ID,
       A.UTL_DTSTAMP,
       /* DATE_FORMAT(A.UTL_DTSTAMP,'%H:%i:%s') AS UTL_DTSTAMP, */
       A.UTL_LATITUDE,
       A.UTL_LONGITUDE,
       A.UTL_EVENT,
       A.UTL_ACTION,
       /* DURATION in seconds  */
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, A.UTL_DTSTAMP, B.UTL_DTSTAMP) AS UTL_DURATION
FROM   tbl_user_time_log A
       INNER JOIN tbl_user_time_log B
               ON B.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID = ( A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID + 1 )
WHERE  A.USER_ID = '465605'
       /* Between current pay period Start date and Current pay period end date */
       /* First day of the week is Monday.*/
       AND ( A.UTL_DTSTAMP BETWEEN '2018-01-22' AND '2018-01-28' )
       /* Filter out Clock Out. */
       AND A.UTL_EVENT <> 'CLOCK OUT'

ORDER  BY A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID ASC

) AS DERIVED_TABLE_1

GROUP BY UTL_ACTION;
```

...and this is what it looks like:

[image: sample2]

Comment: Glad you got it working. Remember that you can remove CLIENT_ID, PROJECT_ID, UTL_DTSTAMP,  UTL_LATTITUDE, UTL_LONGITUDE, UTL_EVENT from the inner select for simplification.